# ERROR: Need more than 1 value to unpack with Read/Write functions

Tags: python

I have to make a program where I take the first letter of the first name and the full last name and join them together to generate a usernames output file from a input file with names. It should be a very simple program so I'm sure it's just a silly mistake I'm making.

This is what my input file looks like -

[INPUT FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMTNp.png)

This is what my code looks like

```
#Introduction to the Program
print("This program creates a file of usernames from names")

#Get the file names

infileName = input("Which file are the names in? ")
outfileName = input("Which file should the names be stored in? ")

#Open the files

infile = open(infileName,"r")
outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

#Process each line of the input file

for line in infile:

    #Get the first and last names from lines

    first, last = line.split()

    #Create the username

    uname = (first[0], last[:7]).lower()

    #Print usernames to the output file

    print(uname, file = outfile)

#Close both files

infile.close()
outfile.close()

#Final print statement

print("Your usernames have been printed to the file", outfileName)
```

[CODE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG4OX.png)

and this is the error that I get when running the code. What am i doing wrong?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Computer Science/Practice Programs/ioTesting.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
    File "/Computer Science/Practice Programs/ioTesting.py", line 30, in main
    first, last = line.split()
    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
    >>>
```

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots, include the actual text. No one is gonna type in your code to run it. Isn't it easier to include the code as text??

Comment: sorry about that i'm new to this whole thing but I'll learn! Let me edit and add it in.

Comment: I didn't see any issues with the `split` line. Each of your lines has 2 words split by a space and so split should behave correctly. Since you already stated that there is not a blank line at the end of the file, then it cant be trying to split some blank space and getting the error. I'd suggest printing out the line before calling `split`. Surround the string in some markers e.g. print('[%s]', line), so its easy to spot a blank line or a line which is only a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print each line? Maybe the last row (which has no name) is causing the problem. Try to print out each row before "first, last = line.split()" and see what is going on first. Otherwise, I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the newline from the end of the names file. (the file with 'Firstname Lastname' format)

If there is a newline, python does something like this when split is called:

```
'\n'.split()
```

Since there are no spaces to split at, the split function returns `'\n'`. This is a single value and cannot be 'unpacked' into firstname, lastname.

Comment: There is no newline at the end of the names file. I haven't pressed <enter> or any other key after stating the last name. (Luthra)

Answer (score 0):

if you're already iterating over every line, you just need to tell split() what to split on -- based on your input lines, you probably want to split on empty spaces:

```
first, last = line.split(' ')
```

if you don't have the reading of input all squared away, you might want something like this:

```
with open('yourfilehere.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        first, last = line.split(' ')
        <do whatever here>
```